# Video upload and sharing to from my IOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, youtube-api, facebook-ios-sdk, youtube-channels

I'm trying to upload user videos to facebook ,youtube or etc from my ios app ? 
I knew and implemented the youtube and facebook api to upload the video for user's account. But at same time i want to video upload on my channel or group with user information also? I saw one option in youtube channel account setting page they given one email id to attached video to upload my youtube account. Upload was done but i dint get user information? 
i all user  can see all video and whom can uploaded it? its possible please advice how to implement.